# PHP datetime different in minute?

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have two date time,
date1 = '2012/10/18 14:12:12'
date2 = '2012/10/18 14:20:12'

and the date2-date1 is 8 in minute. I want to get the diffrent in minutes.

But if the date2 > date1

date1 = '2012/10/18 14:02:12'
date2 = '2012/10/18 14:10:12'

Then I want to get the -8 result.
How can I do this in php?

Answer (score -1):

Look into the [Datetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) class.

You will need `Datetime::createFromFormat()` (to convert your strings into Datetime objects) and `Datetime::diff()` (which will give you the difference between any two Datetimes, divided into years, months, days etc.).

Comment: Okay I'm dump I chek if the date2 > date1 i calcute it and I put a - before the result